# How to set correct path to public folder in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

Zend Framework is totally new for me, and I have problem with it. Probably it's easy to fix, but I can't find any solution in Google.

I can't figure out how to set correct path to public folder. Im using xampp as virtualhost, my current full path looks like this:

```
localhost/zf_project/public/controller/action
```

Now, when I'm using forms and links it moves me to `localhost/controller/action`, so currently I'm adding everywhere:

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();  
$form->setAction($front->getBaseUrl().'/controller/action');
```

Probably there is simplest way to set default path to public folder.
I tried add in my .ini application file:

```
resources.frontController.baseurl = "/zf_project/public"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ZF can determine your base URL without having to set it in your config file or from the bootstrap.

From views, you can construct links with the base URL using the [`baseUrl`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.baseurl) helper.

```
// resolves to localhost/zf_project/public/controller/action
$this->form->setAction($this->baseUrl('controller/action'));

// or

// resolves to localhost/zf_project/public/images/icons/online.png
<img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl('images/icons/online.png') ?>" />
```

You can construct URLs using the [`url`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial) helper.  This constructs your URLs based on the routes configured.

```
// localhost/zf_project/public/controller/action/id/1234
echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'controller',
                      'action'     => 'action',
                      'module'     => 'default', 
                      'id'         => 1234));
```

You can use either of these helpers from your controllers too, just specify the view object when you want to call them:

```
$this->view->baseUrl();
$this->view->url($params);
```

Pretty much anywhere I reference images, javascripts, css files, or static content I use the `baseUrl` helper.  Any time I want to link to other controllers or actions within my application, I use the `url` helper since it constructs valid URLs using your routes.  That way if you change your URL structure, the `url` helper will reflect the changes and you don't have to modify your existing code.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify your virtual host file.

It is **standard practice** to have Zend applications on base root.

In your XAMP (I am not much of Windows but, will give a try), you should have a folder as : `/xampp/apache2/conf` there you will find apache2.conf or httpd.conf, either of them. Open them, you should find `DocumentRoot` somewhere, navigate that with your `/public` folder.

Alternatively, make a new [virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) altogether.

Also, I found [this good tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/zend-framework-from-scratch/), follow it step by step (or jump over to step 3)

Hope it helps :)

Questions?

Comment: I'm not sure its standard practice to have applications in the document root, at least I've never seen that mentioned anywhere.  Certainly relying on that is bad practice IMO.

Comment: I said, Document Root because his host is localhost. However, I have pointed to a quick Google link which I found where even that author wants zf app to be on a custom host (if not localhost) rather be part of `/zf_project/public/` .